# How to print angular object in angular 4

Tags: json, angular

How to print json value, I am very basic like angular, please some one help me.

**test.html**

```
{{ projects }}
<li *ngFor="let obj of projects">{{obj | json }}</li>
```

**services.ts**

```
getProjects(): Promise<Addtimesheet[]> {
    return this.http.get("http://192.168.1.90/EMS/api/TimeSheetAPI/getProjects")
      .toPromise()
      .then(this.extractData)
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }
  private extractData(res: Response) {
    let body = res.json();
    console.log("Sdfsdfsdfsd sss");
    console.log(body);
    return body;
  }

  private handleError(error: any): Promise<any> {
    console.error('An error occurred', error);
    return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
  }
```

**component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Addtimesheet } from './addtimesheet';

import { TimesheetService } from './timesheet.service';

import { Projects } from './projects';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-timesheet',
  templateUrl: './timesheet.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./timesheet.component.css'],
  providers: [TimesheetService]
})
export class TimesheetComponent implements OnInit {

  timesheet = {};
  today: any;

  private projects: Projects[] = [];
  private errorMessage: any = '';

  constructor(private timesheetService: TimesheetService) { 
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.timesheetService.getProjects()
    .then(projects => this.projects = projects)
    console.log(this.timesheetService.getProjects());
  }
}
```

**json value**

```
[
    "AESEMS",
    "ChainDrive",
    "CICAND",
    "CICAPI",
    "CICiOS",
    "CICWeb",
    "KC_APPTV",
    "KCMagento",
    "RDLSWeb",
    "Riddles",
    "TB",
    "TBAND",
    "TBiOS",
    "TestProject"
]
```

I tried, ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

Showing kind of error.

Comment: Please show whole component.ts file.

Comment: @szmitas updated component.ts

Comment: Maybe the backend is unexpectedly not sending a promise: In your service, `extractData` method, what does `Array.isArray(body)` say?  Also, maybe your client is messing with you. Are you using HttpClient or Http in your service? If HttpClient, it should already give you JSON (although it doesn't look like it in your code).

Comment: Are you sure your service is returning an Array ?

Comment: really sounds to me that you are not getting an array. Please check the response tab in dev tools and copy paste that to your question :)

Answer (score 37):

To print JSON:

```
<pre> 
  <code>
     {{ obj | json }}
  </code>
</pre>
```

Or to print it out to console:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

Comment: showing same error. ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

Comment: doesn't seem like a JSON obj... can you output to console to see what type of object it is?

Comment: This value [
    "AESEMS",
    "ChainDrive",
    "CICAND",
    "CICAPI",
    "CICiOS",
    "CICWeb",
    "KC_APPTV",
    "KCMagento",
    "RDLSWeb",
    "Riddles",
    "TB",
    "TBAND",
    "TBiOS",
    "TestProject"
]

Answer (score 1):

Considering

```
projects = [ "AESEMS", "ChainDrive", "CICAND", "CICAPI", "CICiOS", "CICWeb", "KC_APPTV", "KCMagento", "RDLSWeb", "Riddles", "TB", "TBAND", "TBiOS", "TestProject" ]
```

To output the JSON array as it is

```
[ {{projects}} ]
```

To output value one after another

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let project of projects"> 
     {{project}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

I hope it helps.