# ngFor didn't get any data from array object

Tags: javascript, angular, api

The `ngFor` doesn't display the items. Is it because of that value below was evaluated just now error in console? Any way to fix this?

Service to get data:

```
  getBooks(id) {
    return this.httpClient.get(
      `${this.BooksApiService.baseUrlBooks}detail/${id}/`,
      {
        headers: this.headers,
      }
    );
  }
```

Component:

```
  books: any = [];
  bookId : any;

ngOnInit() : void {
    this.route.paramMap.subscribe(params => {
      this.booksId = params.get('detail')
    })

    this.getBooks(this.bookId).subscribe(books => {
      this.books.push(books)
    });
    console.log(this.books)
  }
```

Template:

```html
<div *ngFor="let book of books">
    <div *ngFor="let result of book.results">
        <h3>{{result.id}}</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

Postman JSON from http://localhost:8000/api/books/detail/1[ params url ]/

```
{
    "message": "Visit Added",
    "results": {
        "user": {
            "id": 1,
            "username": "imboyo"
        },
        "id": 1,
        "title": "A Story About a Grandpa and Grandma Who Returned Back to Their Youth",
        "alternative_titles": [],
        "artist": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Araido Kagiri"
            }
        ],
    ...
}
```

[image: My Console Log from console.log(this.books) in component]

Comment: *ngFor="let result of book.results" ,  ngFor only works on array , but book.results is an object so it won't work

Comment: @Mabrur book.results is an object or an array of objects?

Comment: i'm use that code in my other page and thats work, the different in console log error `value below was evaluated just now`

Comment: @Mabrur please mention the console error you are facing in the question section

Comment: @ng-suhas book.results is an array from my API

Comment: I think instead of this.books.push(books) it should be this.books.concat(books)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56554241/how-to-fix-value-below-was-evaluated-just-now-in-angular-7

Comment: @ng-suhas already tried thats solution but still didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's just the timing issue. Can you restructure the code something like below and please let me know if that fixes your issue.

**Method 1:**

**.ts**

```
 books: any = [];
  bookId : any;

ngOnInit() : void {
    this.route.paramMap.subscribe(params => {
      this.booksId = params.get('detail');
      this.getBooks(this.bookId).subscribe(books => {
         this.books.push(books);
         console.log(this.books);
      });
    });
  }
```

**.html**

From the image provided, result is not an array, and its an object. So change your HTML something like below.

```
<div *ngIf="books && books.length > 0>
     <div *ngFor="let book of books">
            <h3>{{book.result.id}}</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Explanation:**

First thing in the typescript file, we cannot say whether booksId gets the value before doing the API call, so I have restructured as you have execute the API call only after getting the booksId value.

In HTML you can render into the DOM only if the array length is greater than 0. You are receiving "value below was evaluated just now" due to the change detection mechanism in angular.

**Reference:**
https://ionic-framework.programmingpedia.net/en/knowledge-base/45496171/cannot-get-the-data-due-to--value-below-was-evaluated-just-now-

[how to fix "value below was evaluated just now" in angular 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56554241/how-to-fix-value-below-was-evaluated-just-now-in-angular-7)

**Method 2:**

Can you try console.log using JSON.stringify something like below.

**.ts**

```
 books: any = [];
 bookId : any;

ngOnInit() : void {
    this.route.paramMap.subscribe(params => {
      this.booksId = params.get('detail');
      this.getBooks(this.bookId).subscribe(books => {
         this.books.push(books);
         console.log(JSON.stringify(this.books, null, 2));
      });
    });
  }
```

Reference: https://medium.com/@decker/javascript-developer-console-fe6fa491654a

Comment: @MabrurSyamhur Sure

Comment: console.log(this.books) `https://i.stack.imgur.com/Arnnm.png`

Comment: @MabrurSyamhur Have you placed console.log after the push statement?

Comment: @MabrurSyamhur You can also try out the Method 2

Comment: srry i'm forgot about that, my console log has changed but the ngFor still didn't work [ https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Ifmo_QB3Epd0pHazOvqEzK4I-TWjdlz0/view?usp=sharing ]

Comment: @MabrurSyamhur From the image, I could see that result is an object and it's not an array. So you cannot ngFor it to print the id. You can find the updated answer.

Comment: can i use this solution [ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48021514/how-to-print-angular-object-in-angular-4/48021534 ]

Comment: @MabrurSyamhur Thats the same thing I have recommended in this answer. You can use JSON.stringify to log the details and you can loop through ngFor as I have mentioned in the answer

Answer (score 1):

**To Get Data from Api In Angular**

**Servie.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Http, Headers, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { environment } from '../../../environments/environment';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class Service {

    constructor(private http: Http) { }


 GetData() {
        return this.http.get('APIURL').pipe(map((response: any) => response.json()));
    }
```

**Component**

```
    public APIDATA : string;
    ngOnInit(){
        this.Service.GetData().subscribe((res) => {
           console.log(res);
           this.APIDATA = res;           
        }
      }
```

**HTML**

```
<div *ngFor="let data of APIDATA">
    <div>
        <h3>{{data}}</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```